# Why is my Async Task not Prccessing Bitmaps In doInBackground

Tags: java, android

I have this AsyncTask which I want to Process Bitmap in,what i want to do is to cache the image and send the bitmap to the activity where it could be posted or saved to local storage, the code is working in some android Versions and not working in some, Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

See the code....

```
// Async task for onClick
class Forward extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Object>
{
    // Before forwarding
    @ Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        linlaHeaderProgress.bringToFront();
        photoEditorView.pause();
        photoEditorView.invalidate();
    }


    // Forwarding
    @ Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object ... arg0)
    {
        Intent forward = new Intent(selfRef, SaveResultingPhotoActivity.class);
        photoEditorView.buildDrawingCache(true);
        photoEditorView.buildDrawingCache();
        photoBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photoEditorView.getDrawingCache());
        saveImage();
        forward.putExtra("com.vanniatech.mImageCache",
                    cacheImage_forPassing.getPath());
        startActivity(forward);
        photoEditorView.buildDrawingCache(false);
        return "DONE";
    }


    // After forwarding
    @ Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
    {
        photoEditorView.buildDrawingCache(true);
        photoEditorView.buildDrawingCache();
        photoBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photoEditorView.getDrawingCache());
        saveImage();
        linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating and Intent and starting the activity in the doInBackground() method. That is a no no as starting an activity from the background is not what you want. Starting the activity should be done in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: Or you can do it via runOnUiThread method of a context reference if you have it in the asynctask. If you want to do this and avoid reference leaks, save the context reference in a WeakReference and always have null checks before using the reference.